# tinymce.get() returns error after ajax request

Tags: plugin-development, tinymce, wp-editor

In the backend, after an event I make an ajax request which populates certain fields. The problematic field is the textarea, for which I use wp_editor like so:

```
<?php $settings = array( 'textarea_rows' => 6 ); ?>
<?php wp_editor('', 'pd', $settings); ?>
```

Upon success, I have the following:

```
tinymce.get('pd').setContent(response.description);
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
TypeError: tinymce.get(...) is null
```

I guess it is not finding the textarea in question, but I do not know how to remedy this.

Comment: Do you create the TinyMCE instance in the AJAX file?

Comment: no, how would I do that?

Comment: Like this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/130425/73

Comment: So I guess the point is to include editor_js and enqueue_scripts functions? My plugin is procedural, is there any way i can just add these procedurally to my ajax request function?

Comment: Sure, it is the same code, just without the objects.