# How to create WP Editor using javascript

Tags: posts, javascript, editor, post-content

I am trying to create some kind of repeated fields and for that, I want to create a new wp editor with some unique ID.

So my question is there any way to create `wp_editor` using any js? same as we get using `<?php wp_editor() ?>` WordPress function.

I have tried using

```
tinyMCE .init( { mode : "exact" , elements : "accordion_icon_description_"+response.success.item_count });
```

but it prints very basic editor which is I think not same as of WordPress post content field editor

Comment: 4.8 introduced a way to do this: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2017/05/20/editor-api-changes-in-4-8/ 
I'm not adding anything so I won't post as an answer, but maybe someone with some examples can.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to [Jacob Peattie's comment](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/274592/how-to-create-wp-editor-using-javascript#comment407500_274592) I can answer this using JS only. Actually we did something similar, but prior 4.8 and it wasn't this easy, so we did use `wp_editor()` in the end. But now, you can do so [using `wp.editor` object in JavaScript](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2017/05/20/editor-api-changes-in-4-8/). There are 3 main functions

1. `wp.editor.initialize = function( id, settings ) {`

Where `id` is

> The HTML id of the textarea that is used for the editor.
>   Has to be jQuery compliant. No brackets, special chars, etc.

and `settings` is either an object

```
{
    tinymce: {
        // tinymce settings
    },
    quicktags: {
        buttons: '..'
    }
}
```

with these [TinyMCE settings](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/integration-and-setup/). Instead of any of the 3 objects (`settings` itself, `tinymce` or `quicktags`) you can use `true` to use the defaults.

2. `wp.editor.remove = function( id ) {`

Is quite self-explanatory. Remove any editor instance that was created via `wp.editor.initialize`.

3. `wp.editor.getContent = function( id ) {`

Well, get the content of any editor created via `wp.editor.initialize`.

---

Usage could look like so

```
var countEditors = 0;
$(document).on('click', 'button#addEditor', function() {
    var editorId = 'editor-' + countEditors;
    // add editor in HTML as <textarea> with id editorId
    // give it class wp-editor
    wp.editor.initialize(editorId, true);
    countEditors++;
});
$(document).on('click', 'button.removeEditor', function() {
   // assuming editor is under the same parent
   var editorId = $(this).parent().find('.wp-editor');
   wp.editor.remove(editorId);
});
```

As the content will be automatically posted, it is not needed in this example. But you could always retrieve it via `wp.editor.getContent( editorId )`

Comment: I checked by initializing the editor with textbox ID
wp.editor.initialize(editorId, true);
but It is not working.

Comment: Is the editor already in the DOM, is the ID correct? Can you share your JS code (in a pastebin)?

Comment: Yes, the textbox is in meta field. 
I am checking it in document.ready 
and also checked by firing the code in browser console
it giving undefined for every text box. those which are actually a post meta field.

Comment: I can't share the entire code because that will be meaning less. That is part of something big.

Comment: For your information my code is 
wp.editor.initialize("accordion_icon_description_1", true);

Comment: @kero, I am also getting the issue. can you help me out with this issue? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/382108/editor-not-displaying-dynamically-after-clicking-on-the-button

Answer (score 7):

**WP 5.3.2**

Currently building a plugin with Ajax page loading, needed to get data from multiple WP editors that are dynamicly loaded.

> NOTE: Below example is for the wp-admin area, if you want this for the
>   front-end you may need to extend.

1.
Make sure editor scripts are loaded with:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_admin_scripts');
function load_admin_scripts() {
  // Do NOT load it on every admin page, create some logic to only load on your pages
  wp_enqueue_editor();
}
```

2.
Get editor textarea with Ajax (PHP):

```
function your_ajax_get_editor_callback() {
  // Note: every editor needs its own unique name and id
  return '<textarea name="my-wp-editor" id="my-wp-editor" rows="12" class="myprefix-wpeditor">The value from database here :-)</textarea>';
}
```

3.
Use Ajax JS script to load and remove the WP editors on Ajax success callback.

> I'm still playing around with all the available tinymce plugins, see
>   TinyMCE docs and note that WP has renamed some of them. Check
>   `wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins`. In the example below I've added
>   `fullscreen`, a handy plugin that's default off.

```
var active_editors = [];

function ajax_succes_callback() {
  remove_active_editors();
  init_editors();
}

function remove_active_editors() {
  $.each( active_editors, function( i, editor_id ) {
    wp.editor.remove(editor_id);
  }
  active_editors = [];
}

function init_editors() {

  $.each( $('.myprefix-wpeditor'), function( i, editor ) {

    var editor_id = $(editor).attr('id');
    wp.editor.initialize(
      editor_id,
      {
        tinymce: {
          wpautop: true,
          plugins : 'charmap colorpicker compat3x directionality fullscreen hr image lists media paste tabfocus textcolor wordpress wpautoresize wpdialogs wpeditimage wpemoji wpgallery wplink wptextpattern wpview',
          toolbar1: 'bold italic underline strikethrough | bullist numlist | blockquote hr wp_more | alignleft aligncenter alignright | link unlink | fullscreen | wp_adv',
          toolbar2: 'formatselect alignjustify forecolor | pastetext removeformat charmap | outdent indent | undo redo | wp_help'
        },
        quicktags: true,
        mediaButtons: true,
      }
    );

    // Save id for removal later on
    active_editors.push(editor_id);

  });

}
```

4.
Get the content from each editor with:

```
function get_editor_content() {

  // NOTE: in my app the code below is inside a fields iteration (loop)

  var editor_id = $(field).attr('id');

  var mce_editor = tinymce.get(editor_id);
  if(mce_editor) {
    val = wp.editor.getContent(editor_id); // Visual tab is active
  } else {
    val = $('#'+editor_id).val(); // HTML tab is active
  }

}
```

---

**Pointers:**

- Use `wp.editor.initialize(editor_id_here)` on a clean `<textarea>`, do not use `wp_editor()` for html output.
- Make sure you remove the editor with `wp.editor.remove(editor_id)` if its no longer present in the dom. If you do not do this, the editor init will fail when you load the editor (dynamicly) for a second time.
- Getting the editor content is different for each tab (Visual / HTML)

---

> NOTE: The above code samples are not fully tested and may contain some
>   errors. I have it fully working in my app. It's purely to get
>   you going.

Comment: Thanks, your info need improvement. but finally success with this code.

Comment: Glad I could help. I think you have enough reputation to add the improvements by clicking on edit so I can review them.

Comment: removing previously initialized editor with *wp.editor.remove(editor_id)* was crucial to make it work for me, thank you

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `wp_enqueue_editor();` first to output the editor scripts, stylesheets, and default settings. You can find this documented here [wp_enqueue_editor()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_editor/)

You need to remove true from function like so: `wp.editor.initialize(editorId);`

Answer (score 0):

```
tinymce.execCommand( 'mceAddEditor', true, element.id );
```

did the trick for me.
Thanks to Goran Jakovljevic's answer on: [How to load wp_editor via AJAX](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/106639/how-to-load-wp-editor-via-ajax)

Comment: Is there a way to load Gutenberg instead of Tinymce?