# Multiple TinyMCE on button click is initialized and appended but why only last one is writeable?

Tags: plugin-development, javascript, html, tinymce

I am using a button click to add TinyMCE dynamically. Everything is working except only one issue is that only the last one is writeable.
Below is my HTML

**HTML**

```
<div id='add_content_box'></div>
<button id='add_more_content_block' class='button'>Add more content</button>
```

and this is my Javascript to create and initialize TinyMCE *wp.editor.initialize('editor_id');*

***Javascript***

```
var counter = 1;
document.getElementById('add_more_content_block').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var editor_id = "editor_"+counter;

    // document.getElementById('wp-editor_0-editor-container').innerHTML += `<textarea name="_hus_landing_page_content[`+counter+`]" id="editor_`+counter+`" ></textarea>`
    document.getElementById('add_content_box').innerHTML += `<div class="wp-`+editor_id+`-editor-container">
        <textarea class="wp-editor-area" name="_hus_landing_page_content[]" id="`+editor_id+`" ></textarea>
    </div>`;

    wp.editor.initialize(editor_id,{
        mediaButtons: true,
        tinymce: true,
        quicktags: true 
    });
    
    counter++;
});
```

I also have enqueued the scripts for editor.

***PHP enqueue script***

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_admin_scripts');
function load_admin_scripts() {
   wp_enqueue_editor();
}
```

I am not much familiar with WordPress TinyMCE API.

Comment: where does `counter` come from? It just appears out of nowhere with no definition or initial value, can you include where it's first defined? You should also avoid constructing HTML by joining up strings for security reasons, it would be much safer and faster to create Dom nodes properly. What does your browsers error console say?

Comment: Okay, I added the code for `var counter = 1` I missed it while adding my code and there is no error in my console so far.

Comment: And when you say it isn't editable can you be more specific? Your changes don't get saved? You're typing but nothing appears? Errors? you can't select inside the instance? It's disabled? Be very specific/precise/detailed

Comment: I strongly suspect this approach is a non-starter and that `wp.editor` doesn't support this use case

Comment: Infact I suspect this is an indirect duplicate of https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59762/instantiate-tinymce-via-js-rather-than-php-wp-editor

Comment: @TomJNowell every time I click on **Add more** button, it adds one more editor but the rest of the editors are empty and I cannot add anything to them.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, with many hours of debugging and I finally came to know why it was not working. So everything is supposed to work the way it should be but there was a minor mistake in my JavaScript.

***Previous JavaScript***

```
var counter = 1;
document.getElementById('add_more_content_block').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var editor_id = "editor_"+counter;

    
    document.getElementById('add_content_box').innerHTML += `<div class="wp-`+editor_id+`-editor-container">
        <textarea class="wp-editor-area" name="_hus_landing_page_content[]" id="`+editor_id+`" ></textarea>
    </div>`;

    wp.editor.initialize(editor_id,{
        mediaButtons: true,
        tinymce: true,
        quicktags: true 
    });
    
    counter++;
});
```

The only problem with the above code `innerHTML`. Everytime you call innerHTML, it will reset all of your **HTML** back to the original condition. So to avoid this, we have to append. So my final solutions is this

***Final Javascript***

```
var counter = 1;
document.getElementById('add_more_content_block').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var editor_id = "editor_"+counter;


jQuery("#add_content_box").append('<textarea id="'+editor_id+'" name="content_block[]" class="form-control"></textarea>');

    wp.editor.initialize(editor_id,{
        mediaButtons: true,
        tinymce: true,
        quicktags: true 
    });

    counter++;
});
```

Everything else will be the same.
I hope that will help someone in the future.